# R Markdown - cross reference an HTML table without `kable`

Tags: r-markdown, bookdown

All the questions regarding table cross-referencing in a Rmarkdown document require using `kable` to cross-reference. How can I cross-reference an HTML table not produced from `kable`? For example, using the `table1` package:

````
---
title: Test Table Cross-Reference
output: bookdown::html_document2
---

This should be a cross reference to table \@ref(tab:table).

```{r table, echo = FALSE}
table1::table1(~depth + table + price | cut, data = ggplot2::diamonds)
```
````

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is not as easy as with kable, where knitr automatically creates the link and reference and inserts both into the final HTML document. However, if you can live without automatic numbering it is easy to create links yourself.

You can create a caption using HTML, anchor it via the argument `id` and then link to that anchor like this (this is similar to what knitr does automatically):

````
This should be a cross reference to table [1](#tab:table)

```{r table2, echo = FALSE}
table1::table1(~depth + table + price | cut, data = ggplot2::diamonds)
```

<center><p id='tab:table'> Table 1: Your Caption</p></center>
````

Note that `table1::table1()` also has an option `caption` to which you may pass a a character string, so something like this works too:

````
```{r table2, echo = FALSE}
table1::table1(~depth + table + price | cut, data = ggplot2::diamonds,
               caption = "<p id='tab:table'> Table 1: Your Caption</p>")
```
````

[image]

Comment: Thanks! Sucks about automatic numbering but still better than nothing!